# Sort a column by name with query between tabs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am pulling information from one tab to another and I believe this is why it will not allow me to sort (because it is not sorted in the original tab). The easy solution would be to sort that tab. However, this is not an option. Is there something I can add to my query code to allow it to sort column A by ascending? My query code is here `=Query('Tardy Data Sheet'!L17:R, "Select * Where N = '8th'")`

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].  Also add some sample data.

Comment: =Query({'Tardy Data Sheet'!A17:A,'Tardy Data Sheet'!L17:R}, 
 "Select Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7 
 Where Col4 = '8th'  
 Order by Col1 Asc")

Answer (score -1):

Try
=Query('Tardy Data Sheet'!L17:R, "Select * Where N = '8th' Order by A")

OOPS, Didnt notice ColA isn't in your query range... Use A17:R

Comment: Thank you for your help. It did not work, I did get a message that said, "unable to parse query string for function query 2: No_Column A

Comment: This is correct regarding the use of `order by` but we don't know if by Column A the OP is referring to `'Tardy Data Sheet'!A:A` or to the Column A of the sheet holding the formula.